# Twig errors on v3.1.19

Tags: templating, error

Running Craft 3.1.19 and have started getting twig error in the control panel.  When I click on the utilities link I get this error:

```
Declaration of craft\web\twig\Environment::compileSource(Twig\Source $source) should be compatible with Twig_Environment::compileSource(Twig_Source $source)
```

And when I try to create a new field I get this error:

```
Key "defaultUploadLocationSubpath" in object with ArrayAccess of class "craft\fields\Assets" does not exist.
```

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also got the second error when trying to create a new field and the solution for me was running

```
./craft clear-caches/all
```

after a refresh it started working again

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest release (currently [Craft 3.1.20.1](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#31201---2019-03-27)) should fix your first error.

Not sure if it'll fix your second one, but comment back here if it doesn't.

Comment: upgraded but still getting both errors.  When ever I try to upgrade I get a fatal error but when I hit the back button I see that the upgrade has actually happened and that the version has changed.

Comment: "I get a fatal error" - that makes the update suspect. I'd revert the database to a last known good state, fix whatever is causing the fatal error, then attempt the update again.

Comment: We reverted to the last known good state but we are still getting all kinds of errors.  Can't add fields etc.  Really at a loss as to what to do next. If there is anyway you can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: If this is on a public box and you want to send from Craft CP and SSH access over to support@craftcms.com, we can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Brad I appreciate it but we finally got it figured out.  Rolled back to 3.1.15 and it seems to be good now.  We moved it to a new server which is much faster.  I think on the old server it was just timing out before it could complete an update.